# How to read property names in array from json string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here is the list of data I receive, property names are can be different;

```
{"data":"[
    {   
        "id":"1",
        "name":"aa",
        "email":"aa@aa.com",
        "address":"11"
    },
    {   
        "id":"2",
        "name":"bb",
        "email":"bb@bb.com",
        "address":"22"
    }
]"}
```

**Here is my c# code**

Which I get an error on the 3rd line. `Unable to read json data. Check the url you typed.Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.`

```
 var jsonStr = wc.DownloadString(url);
 JToken outer = JToken.Parse(jsonStr);
 JObject inner = outer["data"].Value<JObject>();

 List<string> keys = inner.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

How can my output be like this;

id
name
emal
address

It would be great if I also consider n level array such as `address > street` and `address > postcode`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var props = jObj["data"][0].Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Name).ToList();
```

BTW: your json is not correct, it should be something like this

```
{data:[
 { "id":"1", 
        "name":"aa",
        "email":"aa@aa.com",
        "address":"11"
    },
    {"id":"2",
        "name":"bb",
        "email":"bb@bb.com",
        "address":"22"
    }
]}
```

See the `"` after `data:` in your question

Comment: updated json string now, but instead of removing it I had to wrap it with `"` as how it comes from the end point.

Comment: @Cem It is still not a valid json. How to parse invalid jsons is out of scope of this question and i don't know how it can be done easily.

Comment: @Cem See `{"data":"[...]"}`. Is it an array of objects or a single string? In this form it is neither.

Comment: Sorry I was passing string instead of object hence the `"`, now it works fine. thanks a lot.